# wget not working but apt-get does

Tags: networking, wget, http-proxy

Although this question relates to Raspbian running on my Raspberry Pi, it feels like it is a more general Linux query....

The Pi is sat on a network which includes a Microsoft TMG server. I have created a 01proxy file in /etc/apt/apt.conf.d/ which contains the http string for the proxy. The line looks like this:

```
Acquire::http::proxy "http://domain\username:password@proxyip:8080/";
```

Where domain is our domain, username is my username, password is my password (which contains non-alphanumeric characters) and proxy IP which is the ip address of our proxy.
As a result, apt-get update / install / upgrade all work fine.
I am now trying to get general internet access working. To do this I have tried each of the following:

```
export http_proxy=http://domain\username:password@proxyip:8080/
export HTTP_PROXY=http://domain\username:password@proxyip:8080/
export http_proxy=http://domain%5Cusername:urlencodedpassword@proxyip:8080/
export HTTP_PROXY=http://domain%5Cusername:urlencodedpassword@proxyip:8080/
export http_proxy=http://username:password@proxyip:8080/
export HTTP_PROXY=http://username:password@proxyip:8080/
export http_proxy=http://username:urlencodedpassword@proxyip:8080/
export HTTP_PROXY=http://username:urlencodedpassword@proxyip:8080/
```

As well as each of the above surrounded by quotes (") but I still cannot get a simple wget to work.

Any ideas?

Comment: Did you try `export http_proxy=http://domain\\username:password@proxyip:8080/` ?

Comment: I have just tried this (had to url encode my password) still nothing with wget

Comment: Could you share the output of Wget. Why exactly does it not work? What is the error? It would be even better if you can share the output with the --debug option when running Wget

Answer (score 2):

Old question but maybe useful for someone looking for a similar problem.

The user didn't explain in his question if he's executing `sudo` or he's using the root account.

I've experienced something similar, wget was working but apt-get wasn't, of course I was behind a corporate firewall.

The thing is, we must export the proxy variables for the user executing the command, in my case it was:

```
export http_proxy=http://stupid_corporate_proxy:8280
export https_proxy=http://stupid_corporate_proxy:8280

mortiz@florida: wget http://us.archive.ubuntu.com
Proxy Request sent awaiting response .... 200 OK

# And when executing apt-get, it fails

mortiz@florida: sudo apt-get update 
couldn't resolve us.archive.ubuntu.com
```

This has sense, because for root (sudo) I didn't export the proxy variables, so the user hadn't the proxy. I logged as root, exported the proxy variables and then apt-get worked.

Other problem could be if there are special characters in the password of the user:

```
export http_proxy=http://domain\username:MyP$ssW0rd@proxyip:8080/
```

We could try escaping special characters:

```
export http_proxy=http://domain\username:MyP\$ssW0rd@proxyip:8080/
```

I hope this might be useful for someone looking for answers.

Answer (score 0):

I suspect that TMG server does not support `Basic` authentication method, and wget doesn't offer anything else: [(source code)](https://github.com/mirror/wget/blob/master/src/http.c#L1973).

So you're out of luck.